# How can I suppress Unix's "command not found" output?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, stdout

My goal: when I type in something that's not a valid Unix command, it gets fed to a special function instead of displaying the "Command not found" message.

I found [this post](http://speaking-my-language.blogspot.com/2008/06/command-not-found-handler-not-only-in.html), which got me halfway there.

```
trap 'if ! type -t $BASH_COMMAND >/dev/null; then special_function $BASH_COMMAND; fi' DEBUG
```

This allows me to run my special function. However the "Command not found" error still appears afterwards.

Is there any way I can tell Bash to suppress that message?  Either in this command, or inside the special function, would be fine.  Thanks!

Comment: "type -t" with any argument to it doesn't generate any error like that even with Bash 3.0. Are you sure you're using bash? Or perhaps special_function is the one that's not found?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Special function is definitely there (I'm using echo in one of my demos :), and yes I'm using Bash, but maybe error is cuz I'm on a Mac?

Comment: Don't know if it's about Mac. The "command not found" message I get is a small case by the way: "bash: fdasfa: command not found", and not "Command not found". You should really make sure that you're running bash. Try to insert echo "$BASH_VERSION" >~/bash_version.txt somewhere on the runtime part of the script. Then check the output sent to that file after you were able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is redirecting stderr. I don't think it's a great solution but could be a starting point. Something like:

```
$BASH_COMMAND 3> /tmp/invalid



if [ -f /tmp/invalid ]; then 
  if [ $(grep -c "command not found" /tmp/invalid) -ne 0 ]; 
     special_function $BASH_COMMAND
     rm /tmp/invalid
  fi
fi
```

Seems a bit clumsy but could work with some adaptation.

Comment: Very clever idea. But how would I run this after every command. Hmm, maybe there's a way I could encapsulate this as a layer inside my special function?  My brain hurts :)

Comment: Thanks, let me have a think and I'll see if I can improve it. Need some kind of way to redirect every bash command through this function, could be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

In ZSH; this can be achieved by adding this to the .zshrc

```
setopt debugbeforecmd
trap 'if ! whence -w "$ZSH_DEBUG_CMD" >& /dev/null; then special_function $ZSH_DEBUG_COMMAND;fi' DEBUG
exec 2> >(grep -v "command not found" > /dev/stderr)
```

This will behave in a very weird way in bash; because bash sends the prompt to stderr ( In effect you will be able to see the prompt and anything you type only after pressing the Enter key ). ZSH on the other hand, handles the prompt and stderr as separate streams.

If you can find a way to make bash to send the prompt to some other location ( say /dev/tty ) something similar will work in bash also.

**EDIT :**

It seems that bash versions > 4 have a `command_notfound_handle` function that can do what you want. You can define it in your ~/.bashrc

```
command_notfound_handle {
   special_function $1
   # The command that was not found is passed as the first argument to the fn
}
```

Comment: command_notfound_handle can be used in bash to do thew same if your bash version > 4. I think ubuntu defines something to it; but I am not very familiar with ubuntu. So I could be wrong.